# How do I change this vector function to accept more elements?

Tags: c++, string, vector, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Splitting a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c)

I have this vector function from one of the answers I got on my question

```
vector<string> split(const string& s, char delim)
{
  vector<string> elems(2);
  string::size_type pos = s.find(delim);
  elems[0] = s.substr(0, pos);
  elems[1] = s.substr(pos + 1);
  return elems;
}
```

However, it only accept 2 elements. How do I modify it to accept based on how many delimiter s exist in the string s?

e.g if I have this:

```
user#password#name#fullname#telephone
```

sometime the size might differ.

How can I make this function flexible to work no matter how many elements, and able to split like this function above?

**Just to further explain my problem:**

What i wanna achieve is the capability to split using this vector function, of the same delimiter to N size instead of fixed at size 2.

This function can only split maximum 2 element in a string, more than that result in Segmentation core dump

as previously i only have needs for usage like

```
user:pass
```

now i added more attribute so i need to be able to split

```
user:pass:name:department
```

which x[2] and x[3] will return respectively name and department

they all will be using same delimiter.

**Further Update:**

I tried using this function provided by 1 of the answer below

```
vector<string> split(const string& s, char delim)
{
bool found;
vector<string> elems;
  while(1){
   string::size_type pos = s.find(delim);
   if (found==string::npos)break;
   elems.push_back(s.substr(0, pos));
   s=s.substr(pos + 1);
  }
  return elems;
}
```

and i get some error

```
server.cpp: In function ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > split(const string&, char)’:
server.cpp:57:22: error: passing ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string<char>]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: no, it's not a duplicate of *that* question. no doubt someone else has asked the same question. but until such a question is found, please refrain from voting to close on the basis of "i don't understand the question"

Comment: @close-voters: what's the hurry? do something positive instead!

Comment: Not sure what you want to do. Do you want to have a collection of admissible delimiters so splitting `user#password@name@fullname` with the delimiter set `{#@}` would result in 4 elements? Please clarify.

Comment: Well you want to do something 'n' times, so that means you write a loop. You want to add items to a vector, for that you use vector::push_back. You already have the method to find characters in a string and to split a string. It's just matter of putting these together in the right way. This is normal programming. Have a go yourself, and if you get stuck post your attempt and someone will help. You'll learn more this way.

Comment: duplication...
read this article:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c

Comment: @bitmask, as you can see in my sample function above, i can split with that function, but it can only accept maximum 2 element size. I want to make the function flexible to accept N size of same delimiter.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Now I get it: You simply want to it to produce the correct number of elements altogether, for a given (fixed) delimiter.

Comment: @user1587149 but you have to find `N` first, for which you probably have to loop over the string, and use `push_back` to add elements to the vector each time.

Comment: @kain64b: No, as Alf has noted, that question asks for splitting with white space, which allows for more tricky things than splitting with arbitrary delimiters.

Comment: I know that I need to use push back, but where could i find a code of similar situation, I not sure how to find N size in the string using loop.

Comment: @user1587149 You don't need to find N, this is not a for loop it's a while loop. You just keep going until you find no more delimiters. If string::find fails, it returns a special value called string::npos. That's when you stop your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/236137/430766) to the almost-duplicate that provides a generic split functionality:

```
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string const& str, std::string const& delimiters = "#") {
  std::vector<std::string> tokens;

  // Skip delimiters at beginning.
  string::size_type lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, 0);
  // Find first "non-delimiter".
  string::size_type pos = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);

  while (string::npos != pos || string::npos != lastPos) {
    // Found a token, add it to the vector.
    tokens.push_back(str.substr(lastPos, pos - lastPos));
    // Skip delimiters.  Note the "not_of"
    lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, pos);
    // Find next "non-delimiter"
    pos = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);
  }
  return tokens;
}
```

which can be easily wrapped to:

```
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string const& str, char const delimiter) {
  return split(str,std::string(1,delimiter));
}
```

Comment: server.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
server.cpp:152:46: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]

Comment: server.cpp: In function ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > split(const string&, char)’:
server.cpp:50:44: error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘char’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > split(const string&, char)’

Comment: @user1587149: You *did* paste *both* functions into your file, right?

Comment: @user1587149: Just a hint; You may want to try to understand what's going on there, instead of just copy/pasting everything that's presented to you here.

Comment: how can i change the code so the delimiter won't be fix to '#' , I might use other delimiter sometime.

Comment: @user1587149: What are you talking about? The delimiter is not fixed at all.

Answer (score 1):

something like this %)

```
  vector<string> elems;
  while(1){
   string::size_type pos = s.find(delim);
   if (found==string::npos)break;
   elems.push_back(s.substr(0, pos));
   s=s.substr(pos + 1);
  }
  if(s.size())elems.push_back(s);
  return elems;
```

Comment: How do i use it in a function?

Comment: I think this algorithm misses the last token.

Comment: Good grief you really want it on a plate don't you. Are you incapable of wrapping that code in a function? Compare the code above with the function you were given earlier. It's not so hard, you might just learn something.

Comment: @juanchopanza I predict another question in a few days time. 'I was given this function in an earlier question but ...'. Sorry user1587149 but at some point, if you want to learn programming, you are going to have to start at least trying to do things for yourself.

Comment: @jahhaj yeah, I can see this question coming back to haunt us :-)

Comment: I tried, but i got some issues here . Some error, I see the 2 codes are similar , as in this function here and the function I provide above, but I not sure why it result in some error.

Answer (score 0):

well, you know, check out the `push_back` member function…

Comment: I know there such function, but how do i use it in my vector functon above to make it able works the same and flexible with any element size.

Comment: @user1587149: find documentation of that function. try it out.